# 404 not found error in spring mvc application implementing tiles

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I read several articles regarding this 404 error but to no avail. When i am accessing this project with the base url `http://localhost:8080/chatapplication` I got 404 error.I tried with the url `http://localhost:8080/chatapplication/chat` also but the same result. My code is as follows:-

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abhishek.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition"
                template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="chat" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Chat Application" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/chat.jsp" />
    </definition>
    </tiles-definitions>
```

Controller class is as follows:-

```
package com.abhishek.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Created by CAN14 on 6/21/2016.
 */
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/chat")
    public String index()
    {
        System.out.println("**************");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Please help..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Missing **@Controller** annotation in HelloWorldController class.

Comment: thank you sir..I wrote @Controller( a big mistake it is) but then too 404 not found error..any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Give Order to you tiles view resolver So that you can define other view resolvers as well in case you are returning any view from controller which is not mapped.
from your Controller you are returning "home". Which is not mapped in tiles.xml.
Change it to "chat" and you will see the chat.jsp coming with header and footer as It is mapped in tiles.xml.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

You should also add below to map only single jsp without tile

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```